# backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event fires too fast

Tags: c#, datagridview, backgroundworker

I've got method:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
     {
         Ctransakcja obj = (Ctransakcja)e.UserState;
         string[] row = new string[] { obj.id.ToString(), obj.tytul, obj.kwota, obj.nrkonta,obj.bank };
         dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row); 
     }
}
```

this method adds rows to datagridview.
in dowork event of backgroundworker i call method LoadData which connects to database and fire ReportProgress event.

LoadData:

```
...
while (reader.Read())
{
   obj.id = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
   obj.tytul = reader[1].ToString();
   obj.kwota = reader[2].ToString();
   obj.nrkonta = reader[3].ToString();
   obj.bank = reader[4].ToString();
   //dodanie danych itd
   backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, obj);
   i++;
  // Thread.Sleep(100);
}
...
```

Everything works with `Thread.Sleep(100)`, but without sleep dates in datagridview are mixed and reproduced. I need some WAIT function to check that row is added and call next report progress on next row from database.

thanks

Comment: @CamBruce Because then you can't see the first result until the last result has arrived, instead of being able to see the results stream in as they come in (and can be rendered)

Comment: @CamBruce i know that is best solution, but i think how solve it in this situation i got :)

Comment: @Servy have you got any idea to solve my problem????

Answer (score 0):

The `ReportProgress` event really shouldnt be used to bind your data. It's more for updating a UI control with progress. Bind your data in the background thread, using `Invoke()`

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   obj.id = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
   obj.tytul = reader[1].ToString();
   obj.kwota = reader[2].ToString();
   obj.nrkonta = reader[3].ToString();
   obj.bank = reader[4].ToString();
   //dodanie danych itd


   dataGridView2.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { dataGridView2.Rows.Add(obj);});

}
```

Comment: There's no point in checking `InvokeRequired`.  You *know* you're in a background thread so you *know* you need to invoke.

Comment: True - Old habits die hard, just used to writing it that way. Will update post.

Comment: Personally I've yet to find a single time in which `InvokeRequired` is worth using.  You should always know that a given block of code should be run from the UI thread, or a non-UI thread.  Putting yourself in the position of not knowing whether some code will be run from the UI or a non-UI thread is a *horrible* position to be in, and should be avoided at all possible costs.

Comment: Agreed. Would not want to be in that situation :)

Comment: Invoke() doesnt matter in this sistuation because this works, but the reportprogress is caled without any synchro so this display mixed data in gridview

Comment: As stated in the answer, `ReportProgress` is meant to update the UI with progress, NOT for data binding, which you are doing. Invoke is the correct way to do this.